# How portable is code with #pragma optimize?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, portability, pragma

How portable is code that uses [`#pragma optimize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx)? Do most compilers support it and how complete is the support for this `#pragma`?

Comment: I can tell you that the PS3 version of gcc doesn't support this one.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use it in otherwise portable code? I've only ever seen such pragmas used in code that's already specific to a compiler for other reasons.

Comment: gcc 4.4+ has `#pragma GCC optimize`. You can generally assume that pragmas are not portable.

Comment: *The '#pragma' command is specified in the ANSI standard to have an arbitrary implementation-defined effect. In the GNU C preprocessor, '#pragma' first attempts to run the game 'rogue'; if that fails, it tries to run the game 'hack'; if that fails, it tries to run GNU Emacs displaying the Tower of Hanoi; if that fails, it reports a fatal error. In any case, preprocessing does not continue.*
**-- Richard M. Stallman, The GNU C Preprocessor, version 1.34** ---- #pragma is all about compiler-defined behaviour, i.e., non-portable.

Comment: @hvd: Well, if someone doesn't know how to use `volatile` keyword and wants to enforce memory pages load by the OS he would write a loop reading from each of the page and use that `#pragma` to prevent the compiler from removing it.

Comment: @sharptooth: Only until next code review, when he will (hopefully) be shown the error of his ways, just like the guy using `#pragma once` instead of proper header guards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#pragma` is the *sanctioned and portable* way for compilers to add *non-sanctioned and non-portable* language extensions <sup>*</sup>.

Basically, you never know for sure, and at least one major C++ compiler (g++) does not support this pragma as is.

---

<sup>*</sup>:

From the C++ standard (N3242):

> ### 16.6 Pragma directive *[cpp.pragma]*
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# pragma` *pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line*
>
> causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming manner. Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored.

From the C standard (Committee Draft — April 12, 2011):

> ### 6.10.6 Pragma directive
>
> #### Semantics
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# pragma` *pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line*
>
> where the preprocessing token `STDC` does not immediately follow `pragma` in the
>   directive (prior to any macro replacement)<sup>174)</sup> causes the implementation to behave in an
>   implementation-defined manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the
>   translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming manner. Any such
>   `pragma` that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored.

And here's an example:

```
int main () {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i) {}
}
```

A big part of the C and C++ OpenMP API is implemented as `#pragma`s.

Comment: The C standard C11 6.10.6 is identical (except some special rules regarding #pragma STDC).

Comment: @Lundin: Edited a minute before your comment ;)

Comment: But I checked the actual standard and not just the draft ;)  However, they are identical in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Often this is not a good idea to rely on compiler flags, since each compiler has its own behaviour.

This flag should not be used as it is a compiling level spec you inject into your code.

Normally and theoretically this flag should be ignored by compilers if not used.

Comment: @DevSolar : exact. You're a faster typer than me !

Answer (score 4):

The `#pragma` keyword is portable in the sense that it should always compile despite on the compiler. However, the pragmas are compiler-specific so it's probable that when changing compiler it will complain with some warnings. Some pragmas are wide used, such as these from OpenMP. In order to make the code the most portable possible, you might surround your pragmas with `#ifdef`/`#endif` that depend on the compiler you're using. For example:

```
#ifdef __ICC
   #pragma optimize
#endif
```

Compilers usually define some macros such as `__ICC` that make the code know which compiler is being used.

Answer (score 2):

`#pragma` is not portable, full stop. There was a version of gcc that used to start of a game whenever it came across that

Of the compilers we use at work, two definitely don't support `#pragma optimise`, and I can't answer for the others.

And even if they did, as the command line switches for optimisation are different, the chances are that the options for the pragma would be different.

Comment: The token `#pragma` _is_ portable. What follows is not.

Comment: Other compilers are not forced to support a specific #pragma, but if a compiler does not recognize one, it should be ignored. This is required by the C standard.

Comment: a) that makes it pretty unportable though.
b) and if it recognises what comes after but it has different effects to another compiler? how portable is that?
c) The compiler could recognise the pragma keyword and cause a compilation error. This is permitted behaviour.

Comment: That all does not invalidate that the _token_ named `#pragma` is portable, i.e. sanctioned. That's a funny meta discussion. I was really _meaning_ that one _token_, with the meaning of _preprocessing token_ :)

Answer (score 2):

**Any use of `#pragma` is compiler specific.**

[For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Compiler-specific_preprocessor_features) :
GNU, Intel and IBM :

```
#warning "Do not use ABC, which is deprecated. Use XYZ instead."
```

Microsoft :

```
#pragma message("Do not use ABC, which is deprecated. Use XYZ instead.")
```

Regarding your specific question about the `#pragma optimize`, it is supported by [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) and [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx), but it doesn't mean it will be in the future.

Comment: Huh, where did #warning come from? That one is definitely not portable since it isn't standard C, unlike #pragma.

Comment: `#warning` is not a `#pragma` though. So GCC did implement their non-portable code in a non-portable manner, d'oh.

Comment: @phresnel: it's non-portable in that there's a risk that a future standard could introduce a preprocessor directive `#warning` with a different meaning from gcc's `#warning`. Not all compiler extensions are pragmas, indeed most are not. The reason to implement your extension as a pragma is if you think compilers that don't support the extension should ignore it. In this case, would you rather write GCC-specific code in which the user gets the warning, or more-portable code where you don't know whether the warning will get issued or not? Depends how important the warning is.